# communicate with server and android client through XML

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, out-of-memory

I am communication with server through XML. The XML gone soo much huge that I am now getting OOM error on my Android phone.

I am using URLConnection.

```
 while(null != (xmlResponse =
 reader.readLine())) {
                 sb.append(xmlResponse);
              }
```

reader.readLine() takes tooo much time and finally my app crash. Is there any better way to parse huge XML ??? or any lib ??

Answer (score 1):

If you have OOM when performing a readline it is maybe that your lines are too long. Taking care of limiting to a buffer of few kb when reading would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Android XmlPullParser, so that you perform the parsing while you are downloading.

Comment: I am using XMLPullParser but I could only use it when I can read xml. It gives me OOM error whille reader.readLine()